# bubble sort random numbers C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I have finished the assignment which was generating two arrays of the same random numbers, I would like to arrange them in ascending order. I read ahead to the next chapter, but I don't understand the concept of bubble sort, can anyone point me in the right direction, I would like to sort these into ascending order.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>


int getRandNumb();




int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    int randomNum[8];
    int randomNum2[8];

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        randomNum[i] = getRandNumb();
        cout << randomNum[i] << endl;
    }



    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
    {
        randomNum2[j] = getRandNumb();
        cout << randomNum[j] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
int getRandNumb()
{
    return 1 + rand() % 30;
}
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort  You can also find many examples on here if you search.

Comment: What you have now has nothing to do with bubble sort, just some output statements. The right direction is to at least google *bubble sort* first.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia has a complete article about bubble sort. There you can find a complete description of the algorithm as weel as pseudo-code.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

Note that bubble sort is by no way efficient. In c++11 sorting array is already implemented in an efficient way using `std::sort` in `algorithm`

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/

Answer (score 0):

The concept of a bubble sort is that larger values "bubble" to the top. The algorithm compares adjacent values and swaps them if they are out of order relative to each other. You continue looping though the values until no more swaps take place. That is the very very very high level idea of what is happening.